# How to get rows after a time of day using datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running queries for a ticketing system. I want to extract all tickets created after 6:00PM or 18:00:00 in database/military time.

Could I use a `DATEPART` function or `EXTRACT` function?

Something like this may work:

```
SELECT *
FROM ticket
WHERE TIME IS AFTER 6PM
```

The issue is that the datetime format is as `'2014-12-01 16:13:38'` so I would need to specify for only the characters after the DATE section.

Comment: Check the list of MySQL [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, just use the `hour()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM ticket
WHERE hour(time) >= 18;
```

Comment: Never knew there was an hour function and that is was so specific. There is always something new to learn with SQL. Thanks!!